# Designing a simple UVLO in PSIM

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-protection

I want to create a simple circuit in PSIM that does the same task as a UVLO (under voltage lockout) that only allows voltage to flow when the voltage is above a minimum level (e.g. 5V).
Since PSIM does not have LM741 or elements like that, I cannot consider them in my circuit.

Can somebody recommend an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Generally this is done using Logic gates with a comparator, really depends on what you are trying to do. PSIM has a comparator model that includes hysteresis to make it more realistic like how a UVLO works. Then, you can cascade logic gates with different fault flags that you can think of to give an even more realistic picture of what's happening.

Comment: @RogerDodger Thanks. It worked well.

Comment: do you want me to make that the answer to the thread?

Comment: @RogerDodger sure